# How can a vector have coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If a vector is what carries a point to another point, and it can carry any point on a plane to another point on a plane, then how can it have coordinates ? shouldn't it be the "steps" needed to get the original point to the other point ?

Comment: Is like analytic geometry: we map geometrical entities in the (real) plane. Every *point* in the plane is identified by a couple of numbers $(x,y)$ : its coordinates. See [vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Introduction_and_definition).

Comment: Vectors are objects you can add together or multiply by scalars taken from a field (for example the real numbers). Sensible collections of vectors form "vector spaces" and it is possible to prove that every vector space has a basis. Now the basis is far from unique, but once a basis is chosen, every vector has co-ordinates with respect to that basis. Normally in two or three dimensions (plane, or euclidean space) this is taken for granted - and if you have an origin and co-ordinate axes, vectors inherit co-ordinates from these.

Comment: But in order to visualize it, we have to say that a *vector* is an "arrow" and not a sequence of "steps".

Comment: I think you're unclear about what you're seeking for. What you really want to know may be *How can a vector has so many coordinates.* The answer is **why not**? As long as everything you do is consistent to those definitions and axiom of *vector space*, how one interpret a vector is not that important. IMO, it just different perspective, which makes a vector flexible when using in application.

Comment: Typically you wouldn't regard the vector as having co-ordinates itself, rather its start and end points have co-ordinates. Buy if you wanted you could regard the start and end points of a vector together as the co-ordinates of the vector.

Comment: You might ask yourself another question first: how can a point have coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you say, you may see the vector's coordinates as the coordinates of the destination you'd reach if you started at the origin of the plane (i.e. $(0,0)$). This gives both:

- which direction it has
- how far it "goes"

which is all you need to define a vector.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i am aware that a vector needs only a direction and a length to be defined,I asked the question to get clarification on the addition of vectors,when you add two vectors you seem to add the movements along the x axis and the movements along the y axis to get the sum of the two, this is when the "coordinates" of a vector stop making sense to me and thinking of them as instruction given to reach the destination made more sense.

Comment: Then, you can indeed think of a vector as a movement on the $x$ axis and a movement on the $y$ axis, then adding two vectors consists in adding the movements on each axis. Next time you ask a question, be sure to make it clear what you want an answer to. This way, we will be able to give you much more relevant answers.

Comment: Sorry this is my second time asking a question here so I'm not really accustomed to it, but thanks for the answer, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't worry. Asking a question to better understand your lectures rather than asking the community to solve your homework is already better than what quite a few new users do ;)